# Perforce: How to find changelists submitted in the last X minutes?

Tags: perforce, changelist

Is there a Perforce command to display all the changelists submitted in the last X minutes in a specific branch?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use relative date expressions, but if you compute the value of "X minutes" ago first, you can then say something like

```
p4 changes //depot/branch/name/...@2013/05/24:06:53:00,@now
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for all changes on a particular path between two time stamps.  e.g.:

`p4 changes -s submitted "//depot/branch/...@2013/04/01:12:00:00,@2013/04/01:12:55:00"`

See `p4 help revisions` for details on syntax.